# sailsjs use mongodb without ORM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, sails.js, q

I want to use mongodb with sails but without any ORM. So below is my service to connect mongodb.
Service:

```
//DbService.js

    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    module.exports = {
      db:function(req, res){
        var connect=MongoClient.connect("mongodb:***********").then(function (err, database) {
          if(err) console.log(err);
          else{
            database=database.db('*****');
            return connect;
          }  

        });  
      }
    }
```

After connection i have called it in controller, But getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

controller:

```
//HomeControlelr.js
    module.exports = {
            index:function(req, res){
                DbService.db().then(function(err,db) {
                    console.log(db);
                })
            }
    };
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Waterline is a big part of why most people would use Sails in the first place.

Comment: i only need to fetch the data. I don't want to write scema for all collections.

Comment: `MongoClient.connect()` doesn't seem to return a `Promise`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#connecting-to-mongodb

Comment: As an alternative you can always use waterline [native](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native) features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `npm i mongodb` because you'll need to wrap any ID's with `new ObjectID(idStr)`.

Then you can do this:

```
const collection = Pet.getDatastore().manager.collection(Pet.tableName);
const res = await collection.find({ name: { $regex: /blue/ } });
const dataWithObjectIds = await res.toArray();
const dataWithIds = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rawDataArr).replace(/"_id"/g, '"id"'));
```

I created a helper function to do all of this for us:

```
/**
 * Use by chaining as if you were acting on a collection. So can use .find .aggregate etc.
 * Returns json searializable data.
 *
 * @param {class} model A model
 * @param {number} cnt - Number of chains on this, so I know when it reached the end
 */
function nativeMongoQuery(model, cnt) {

  const collection = model.getDatastore().manager.collection(model.tableName);

  let callCnt = 0;

  let req;

  const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
    get: (_, method) => (...args) => {

      if (!req) req = collection[method](...args);
      else req = req[method](...args);

      callCnt++;

      if (callCnt === cnt) {
        return (async function() {
          const rawDataArr = await req.toArray();
          return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rawDataArr).replace(/"_id"/g, '"id"'));
        })();
      } else {
        return proxy;
      }
    }
  });

  return proxy;

}

module.exports = nativeMongoQuery;
```

I don't like the JSON parse and stringify and global replace. But if I don't do the stringify, then mongo _id's are all `ObjectId`s.

Use it like this:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

function makeObjectId(id) {
   return new ObjectId(id);
}

const ownerIds = ['5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f4', '5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f5']
const ownerObjectIds = ownerIds.map(makeObjectId);
await nativeMongoQuery(Pet, 2).find({ owner: { $in: ownerObjectIds } }).sort({ dueAt: 1 });
```

Here is another example:

```
const mostRecentlyCreatedPets = await nativeMongoQuery(Pet, 1).aggregate([
  { $match: { owner: { $in: ownerObjectIds } } },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
]);
```

The `cnt` argument tells you how many things you have chained off of there.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html) `MongoClient.connect()` doesn't return Promise object. Instead of this use callback function

```
module.exports = {
  db:function(){
    var connect = MongoClient.connect("mongodb:***********", function (err, database) {
      //...
      }  
    });  
  }
}
```

btw. Your call `DbService.db` function in controller will also fail, cuz your service function also doesn't return Promise

Before you go on, read something about Promises and callback functions